# IRQ Conflict between Ethernet Port and USB 2 controller with Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, grub2, kernel, ethernet

I have Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS installed on my HP G72 laptop with the following kernels that could be booted by GRUB:

```
Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency
Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency (recovery mode)
Linux 5.4.0-54-lowlatency
Linux 5.4.0-54-lowlatency (recovery mode)
```

If I select "Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency" my Wired Ethernet Card **does not** obtain an IP address via DHCP.  The Wifi card can.   And I see these entries in DMESG

```
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x7, date = 2018-04-23
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-56-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-amd64-025) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #62-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 23 20:19:44 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-56.62-lowlatency 5.4.73)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-lowlatency root=UUID=f195d3fb-c86f-4430-85e4-4f2bcc8b7d22 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    1.560019] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.570901] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency ehci_hcd
[    1.581961] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency ehci_hcd
[   16.676064] genirq: Flags mismatch irq 16. 00010080 (enp2s0) vs. 00002080 (ehci_hcd:usb1)
```

If I boot "Linux Linux 5.4.0-54-lowlatency" via GRUB, the Wired Ethernet card **does** get an IP address, and I do not see the 'genirq' error in DMESG.

How do I resolve the IRQ conflict between the USB Controller and my Ethernet Board on this specific kernel "Linux 5.4.0-56-lowlatency" ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't have an answer. But I have a detailed report with log files here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1906913 It may be helpful for others to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing version `5.4.0-57` fixed this issue for me.

Steps I took were:

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the line `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed main`  (I added it at the end, which appeared to work)
2. Reboot with version `5.4.0-54` to get internet access, then run the Software Updater

This installed version 5.4.0-57 and my internet access is now OK.

I guess `5.4.0-57` is not officially released yet, so up to you if you think it's worth it.  I should now remove the extra line I added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` to avoid the Software Updater retrieving proposed versions all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem with my Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS for around a month. I ran an `apt update` and `apt upgrade` command and the kernel updated to .59, which fixed the network conflict for me. I would recommend you to do the same.